# LINQ group by on a single column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a database table that looks like this:

```
ID       USERID       DATE            NAME
1        1            01-01-2001      aaaa
1        2            01-02-2001      aaaa
1        3            01-03-2001      aaaa
2        5            02-02-2002      bbbb
2        6            02-02-2002      bbbb
2        7            02-02-2002      bbbb
```

So I want to group everything by `ID`, so it has multiple `USERIDs` for each ID. However `DATE` and `NAME` are all the same. So how do get this as a linq query?

So far I thought of doing this, and this works for the users

```
from table in context.table
group table.USERID by table.ID into grp
orderby grp.Key descending
select new
{
    ID = grp.Key,
    Users = grp.ToList()
}
```

But this does not work if I add other items like `DATE` because `DATE` is sometimes different. However if it would select the first date that would be just fine.

EDIT what I would like as result is:

```
ID       Users        DATE            NAME
1        1,2,3        01-01-2001      aaaa
2        5,6,7        02-02-2002      bbbb
```

Comment: can you elaborate what is the expected result?

Comment: Why does it matter data and name are the same, if ID groups them just group on that

Comment: Made an edit with expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You group by multiple columns:

```
from table in context.table
group new{table.UserID,table.Date} by new{table.ID,table.Name} into grp
orderby grp.Key.ID descending
select new
{
    ID = grp.Key.ID,
    Date=grp.FirstOrDefault().Date,
    Name=grp.Key.Name,
    Users = grp.Select(e=>e.UserID).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Would this work if the dates and names were different across members of a given ID?

Comment: If the names were differents for a given ID, then they'll be in different groups

Comment: That's the problem for me. In some cases the dates are different. Is it possible to just select the first date then?

Comment: @user2657943, check my update, that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Kind of, and it is also what I tried first, but this doesn't work because the return value of grp.FirstOrDefault() is of type int, it's not an object.

Comment: Right, I have fixed that ;)